# Design Pattern advice

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, inheritance, class-design

I was wondering if someone could help me.

Suppose I have some classes as follows:

```
class A { ... };

class B : public A { ... }

class C : public A { ... };

class D { ... };

class E : public D { ... };

class F : public D { ... };
```

Now I want class B to have an object of type E as a member and class C to have a object of type F as a member.

Is there a nice design pattern whereby I can have some sort of base pointer to class D in class A and then create a new E in class B and a new F in class C. I was wondering if abstract factory is similar?.

I hope this is not too confusing ... it is hard to explain without UML diagrams!.

Comment: Formatted your code.  Please do this yourself in future posts.

Comment: Sounds like you should reconsider your design.

Comment: If you want to put a name to the pattern, then it *might* be a restricted form of Strategy, depending what the object is actually for. I say restricted because although from the POV of class A, the member could be any object implementing D, your classes B and C are each restricting that object to specifically their member variable, not any object supplied from "outside". If the only difference between B and C is the different member variable then the whole structure could be re-cast as Policy-based design, that is turn A into a template, and replace `B` with `A<E>` and `C` with `A<F>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with just doing exactly as you say?

```
class A
{
    A(D* p) : ptr(p) {}
    D* ptr;
};

class B : public A
{
    B() : A(new E) {}
};

class C : public A
{
    C() : A(new F) {}
};
```

If you want to automate it a bit better, you can use an intermediate template class.

```
class A
{
    virtual D* getD();
};

template <class T>
class AImpl : public A
{
    AImpl() : m_d(new T) {}
    T* getD() { return m_d; }
    T* m_d;
};

class B : public AImpl<E> { };

class C : public AImpl<F> { };
```

Note that `AImpl::getD()` can return `T*` due to [covariant return types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#C.2B.2B).

Comment: That's not CRTP, though. CRTP means supplying a class itself as a template parameter to a class template used as a base. You're supplying some other class as a template parameter to a class template used as a base.

Comment: Huh, yeah, you're right. For some reason it just seemed like CRTP to me, and I didn't even think about it. I'll correct it. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You can do exactly that:

```
class D
{
public:
    D(const A *p) : p_(p) {}
    virtual ~D() { delete p_; }
private:
    const A *p_;
};

class E : public D
{
public:
    E() : D(new B) {}
};
```

There are many better approaches to this, depending on what you're trying to achieve.  For instance, why does `D` need to contain the pointer to the `A`?

Perhaps if you edit your question to better explain your goal, then we can provide more insightful answers.

Comment: Falmarri said I should reconsider my design. Do you think the above is good practice or would you recommend a different approach?

Comment: @Mewzer: I cannot say, as I don't know what your goal is.

Answer (score 0):

how about Composite Design pattern?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern